# Testing if @ key is pressed in Java

Tags: java

for a program that I am writing I want to test if a few keys are pressed and then determine what to do out the combination of keys. so I got some problems trying to get the @ key to be registered (Shift + 2) I tried this If statement

```
if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2 && ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
```

Why does it not work? I am testing for the 2 and Shift key to be activated at the same time, o does it not work like that?

Comment: How should `ke.getKeyCode()` return two different values if you call that method twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [KeyEvent.VK_AT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_AT) instead of looking for SHIFT + 2.  The `@` symbol isn't in the same place on all keyboards.

So your code becomes:

```
if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_AT) {

}
```

If you *really* want to check if the shift key is being pressed have a look at [InputEvent.getModifiers()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getModifiers()) or [InputEvent.isShiftDown()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isShiftDown())

Based on updates spec in the comments, what you want to do is:

```
if (ke.getKeyChar() == '@') {

}
```

Comment: Updated with how to do that